# React functional component test file unable to update state value and call its props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

i do have a functional parent component and it do have a state value , which have default value as false and it is calling another component which is visible only when the state value changes to true and the child component do have 2 function in it.

Illustrating with code

```
      export const MainSearch = (props) => {
        const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
        
          const closeSearch = () => {
            setSearch(false);
           
            ANALYTICS.trackEvent('popup_collpsed');
          }
        
          const toggleSearch = async () => {
        
            await setSearch(true);
           
              ANALYTICS.trackEvent('popup_expanded');
            }
          };
            return (
             <React.Fragment>   
             <searchBar toggleSearch={toggleSearch} />
                {search  &&
                      <childSearch
                        toggleSearch={toggleSearch}
                        closeSearch={closeSearch}
                      />}
             </React.Fragment>
             )
        }

And its test file with one test case

describe('MainSearch',()=>{
 it('AdvancedSearch - Toggle popup_expanded  and popup_collapsed ', async () => {

     const component = shallow(<MainSearch {...props} />);
     const searchBar = component.find('searchBar');
     await searchBar.props().toggleSearch(); // calling function
     expect(ANALYTICS.trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('popup_expanded');
     const childSearchComponent = component.find('childSearch'); // not working ,since state value hides
     expect(childSearchComponent).toBeDefined();
     await advancedSearchComponent.props().closeSearch();// here getting null for .props()
     expect(ANALYTICS.page.trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('popup_collapsed');
  });
});
```

i know its possible with component.update for CLASS COMPONENTS, but here am using functional components and am getting error

if i remove the state value search , am getting my test case PASS, but cant remove that , its needed. so my test case need to make the state value true and call the function closeSearch and then check the analytics.

BUT am getting error **Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**
I guess state value if false and its not getting that particular node .

Can you guys please help me on same , since am stuck with it and can give more info if needed

Comment: You can **not** return multiple values, not even if you put them in `()`! If you want to return multiple elements you have to enclose them in a [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: @Thomas yes , its just made a minimal code to seek help in stack overflow. i missed it, will add the same. but my problem is what i mentioned above.. can you help me

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your `toggleSearch` function. You're awaiting `setSearch`, which isn't a promise. Remove the `await` Keyword and you should be fine!
If you would want to trigger your `Analytics` call only after the State has been set, you would need to hook in to Reacts useEffect Hook.

Then you could do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(search){
   ANALYTICS.trackEvent('popup_expanded');
 }
}, [search])
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: its not correct .. my problem is am not getting the node in test file. even if i remove aait or not , i need to get the prop() value in test case , but that null

Comment: So maybe check your code first then.
Your example code from above doesn't even render.
Components need to be capitalized.
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: this is very minimal code and i havent metioned anywhere this is a working sample. i just put across code here to get guys understood what i am trying to achieve and seek help..